# Wordpress. Как обернуть блок со статьей в ссылку на эту статью?

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, есть вывод записей на главной странице, сейчас кликабельны тоолько название статьи и изображение. Что нужно изменить в коде, чтобы кликабельным был весь блок записи?

```
    <section class="newsfeed">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">    
      <?php

        $count_posts = wp_count_posts();
        $count_posts_1 = $count_posts - 1;

        $args = array( 
          'post_type' => 'post',
          'posts_per_page' => $count_posts_1
        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
          $query->the_post();

          echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 item box-hidden">
                  <div class="post-img">' . 
                    '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</a>' . 
                    '<div class="cat-name">' . 
                      get_the_category_list(',') . 
                    '</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="post-description">
                    <h3>
                      <a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' .  
                        get_the_title() . 
                      '</a>
                    </h3>
                    <div class="post-meta">
                      <span class="date">' . get_the_date('j F') . '</span>

                      <span class="comment-number">
                        <i class="fa fa-comment-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' . get_comments_number() . 
                      '</span>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>';
        }
        wp_reset_postdata(); 

      ?>
    </div>

    <button id="loadMore" class="primary-button">Показать еще</button>


  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<section class="newsfeed">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">    
        <?php 
        $count_posts = wp_count_posts();
        $count_posts_1 = $count_posts - 1;
        $args = array( 
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => $count_posts_1
        );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 item box-hidden">
            <div class="post-img"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> 
                <div class="cat-name"><?php the_category_list(','); ?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="post-description">
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <div class="post-meta">
                <span class="date"><?php echo get_the_date('j F'); ?></span>
                <span class="comment-number">
                    <i class="fa fa-comment-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <?php echo get_comments_number(); ?>
                </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0;"></a>
            <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
    <button id="loadMore" class="primary-button">Показать еще</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

Здравствуйте.

Обернуть блок в ссылку. Примерно так:

```
 <section class="newsfeed">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">    
      <?php

        $count_posts = wp_count_posts();
        $count_posts_1 = $count_posts - 1;

        $args = array( 
          'post_type' => 'post',
          'posts_per_page' => $count_posts_1
        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
          $query->the_post();

          echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 item box-hidden">
                  <div class="post-img">' . 
                    get_the_post_thumbnail() . 
                    '<div class="cat-name">' . 
                      get_the_category_list(',') . 
                    '</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="post-description">
                    <h3>' . get_the_title() . '</h3>
                    <div class="post-meta">
                      <span class="date">' . get_the_date('j F') . '</span>

                      <span class="comment-number">
                        <i class="fa fa-comment-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' . get_comments_number() . 
                      '</span>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </a>';
        }
        wp_reset_postdata(); 

      ?>
    </div>

    <button id="loadMore" class="primary-button">Показать еще</button>


  </div>
</section>
```